# Python creating class instances in a loop

Tags: python, class, loops, instance

I'm new to python, so I'm pretty confused now. I just want to create a couple of instances of class MyClass in a loop.

My code:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
  my_class = MyClass()
  print "i = %d, items = %d" % (i, my_class.getItemsCount());
  my_class.addItem(i)
```

Class MyClass

```
class MyClass:

  __items = []

  def addItem(self, item):
    self.__items.append(item)

  def getItemsCount(self):
    return self.__items.__len__();
```

And the output is:

```
i = 0, items = 0
i = 1, items = 1
i = 2, items = 2
and so on...
```

But I expect new empty instance of MyClass in variable my_class on each iteration. So expected output is:

```
i = 0, items = 0
i = 1, items = 0
i = 2, items = 0
```

Could you help me with understanding?
Thanks.

Comment: `__items` is a class member, not an instance member. It is shared between all instances of `MyClass`.

Comment: avoid using double underscore, it's only useful in rare cases of inheritance. Use the `len`-function instead of `__len__`-Method, e.g. `len(self._item)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`_items` is a class attribute, initialized during the class definition, so by appending values to it, you're modifying the **class** attribute and **not instance** attribute.

To fight the problem you can create `_items` for each instance of the class by putting this code into `__init__` method:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._items = []
```

Then `_items` list object will be different across all class instances

```
>>> first = MyClass()
>>> first._items.append(1)
>>> second = MyClass()
>>> second._items.append(1)
>>> first._items is second._items
False
```

and therefore appending will work as expected.

Btw, in your case [`__items` is not quite good name choice for a class variable](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references).